How to load ImageNet from Kaggle?
I downloaded the ImageNet dataset from Kaggle, as it seems like the original website doesn't have it anymore. When I try to load it with Pytorch following this:
torchvision.datasets.ImageNet(root: Union[str, Path], split: str = 'train', **kwargs: Any)

I get RuntimeError: The archive ILSVRC2012_devkit_t12.tar.gz is not present in the root directory or is corrupted. You need to download it externally and place it in
As Kaggle doesn't have the same gz file. Instead, the data looks like:
/media/SSD2/ILSVRC/
                |----Annotation
                |----ImageSets
                |----Data
                      |----CLS-LOC
                               |----test
                                      |----ILSVRC2012_val_00000009.JPEG
                                      |----ILSVRC2012_val_00000010.JPEG
                                      |----...
                               |----train
                                      |----n01440764 # this is a class
                                             |----ILSVRC2012_val_00000010.JPEG
                                             |----ILSVRC2012_val_00000010.JPEG
                                      |----n01443537
                                      |----...
                               |----val
                                      |----ILSVRC2012_val_00000009.JPEG
                                      |----ILSVRC2012_val_00000010.JPEG
                                      |----...

I found that people on Kaggle load it differently, and I could not figure out the script they referred to here.
I was loading previous datasets like this so I can use the transformation:
trainset = torchvision.datasets.ImageNet(root='path_to_dataset', split='train', download=False, transform=transform_train)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=bs, shuffle=True, num_workers=8)

Where my transformation is something like
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
    transforms.Resize(size),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)), 
])

I couldn't find an original Pytorch script to load the dataset, which is very bizarre as this is one of the most popular datasets.
Update:
Found here that I can convert the val folder to the same format as the train folder (i.e., move the images to their respective folders). By running
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soumith/imagenetloader.torch/master/valprep.sh | bash


Okay I figured it out!
After downloading the data from Kaggle, follow the script from here:
# extract train data
mkdir train && mv ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar train/ && cd train
tar -xvf ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar && rm -f ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar
find . -name "*.tar" | while read NAME ; do mkdir -p "${NAME%.tar}"; tar -xvf "${NAME}" -C "${NAME%.tar}"; rm -f "${NAME}"; done
# extract validation data
cd ../ && mkdir val && mv ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar val/ && cd val && tar -xvf ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soumith/imagenetloader.torch/master/valprep.sh | bash

This converts the val folder to the same format as the train folder (note that this is not changing anything in the test folder which has the same format as the val folder), where the images are moved towards their respective folder classes.
Next, to load the train and val images I did the following:
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(size),
    transforms.RandomCrop(32),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)), # https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/42e5b996718797e45c46a25c55b031e6768f8440/imagenet/main.py#L89-L101
])

transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)), # https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/42e5b996718797e45c46a25c55b031e6768f8440/imagenet/main.py#L89-L101
])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder('train_path/train' , transform=transform_train)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=bs, shuffle=True, num_workers=8)
testset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder('val_path/val' , transform=transform_test)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False, num_workers=8)

